# form with jquery combined with php to send result *updated with full code*

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, sendmail

**Updating with full code** below. Also adjusting question.

What happens? After all questions are answered endQuiz triggers and gives the user a score. A form also appears which I want the user to fill out and send to a specific e-mail account. But when I fill out the form and press "send" when the quiz is run on my company's server I 1) get a 405 error. When I run this locally nothing happens.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var quiztitle = "quiz title";
     var quiz = [
            {
                "question" : "q1",
                "image" : "http://www.saferinternet.org/image/image_gallery?uuid=b243b830-e3fd-49b9-ad2c-43b2ff073db8&groupId=10137&t=1359909134797",
                "choices" : [
                                        "a1",
                                        "a2",
                                        "a3",
                                        "a4"
                                    ],
                "correct" : "a2",
                "explanation" : "good job"
            },
            {
                "question" : "q2",
                "image" : "http://www.saferinternet.org/image/image_gallery?uuid=b243b830-e3fd-49b9-ad2c-43b2ff073db8&groupId=10137&t=1359909134797",
                "choices" : [
                                        "a1",
                                        "a2"
                                    ],
                "correct" : "a2",
                "explanation" : "good job"
            },
            {
                "question" : "q3",
                "image" : "http://www.saferinternet.org/image/image_gallery?uuid=b243b830-e3fd-49b9-ad2c-43b2ff073db8&groupId=10137&t=1359909134797",
                "choices" : [
                                        "a1",
                                        "a2",
                                        "a3",
                                        "a4"
                                    ],
                "correct" : "a3",
                "explanation" : "good job"
            }
        ];
     var currentquestion = 0,
         score = 0,
         submt = true,
         picked;

         $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#submitbutton").hide();

          function htmlEncode(value) {
             return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
         }

           function addChoices(choices) {
             if (typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array") {
                 $('#choice-block').empty();
                 for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                     $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');
                 }
             }
         }

          function nextQuestion() {
             submt = true;
            //alert("nQ");
             $('#explanation').empty();
             $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
             $('#pager').text('Q ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
             if (quiz[currentquestion].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[currentquestion]['image'] != "") {
                 if ($('#question-image').length == 0) {
                     $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question'])).insertAfter('#question');
                 } else {
                     $('#question-image').attr('src', quiz[currentquestion]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['question']));
                 }
             } else {
                 $('#question-image').remove();
             }
             addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
             setupButtons();
         }

           function processQuestion(choice) {
             //alert(choice);
             currentquestion++;
              //alert(currentquestion);
             $("#submitbutton").hide();

                 if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
                     endQuiz();
                 } else {

                     nextQuestion();
                 }

         }

          function setupButtons() {
             $('.choice').on('mouseover', function () {
                 $(this).css({
                     'background-color': '#e1e1e1'
                 });
             });
             $('.choice').on('mouseout', function () {
                 $(this).css({
                     'background-color': '#fff'
                 });
             })
             $('.choice').on('click', function () {
                 //alert("");
                 choice = $(this).attr('data-index');
                 $('.choice').remove();
                 if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
                 $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                     'background-color': '#50D943'
                 });
                 $('#explanation').html('<p style="background-color:green;">Score! <strong>' + quiz[currentquestion]['correct'] + 'Thats the right answer!</p>' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
                 score++;
             } else {
                 $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                     'background-color': '#D92623'
                 });
                 $('#explanation').html('<p style="background-color:red;">Sorry!' +quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] + 'Thats the wrong answer!</p>' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
             }
                    $("#submitbutton").show();
                 if (submt) {
                    ////alert("submit");
                     submt = false;
                     $('#submitbutton').css({
                         'color': '#000'

                     });
                     $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
                    ////alert("click");
                          $('.choice').off('click');
                         $(this).off('click');
                         processQuestion(choice);
                     });
                 }
             })
         }

          function endQuiz() {
         $('#explanation').remove();
         $('#question').empty();
         $('#choice-block').remove();
         $('#submitbutton').remove();
         $('#question-image').remove();
        if (score > 2) {
            $('#question').text("best " + score + " of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
        }
        if (score > 1 && score < 3) {
            $('#question').text("ok " + score + " of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
        }
        if (score < 2) {
            $('#question').text("poor " + score + " of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
        }
        if (score < 1) {
            $('#question').text("worst " + score + " of " + quiz.length + " correct.");
        }
         $(document.createElement('h2')).css({
             'text-align': 'center',
             'font-size': '4em'
         }).text(Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + '%').insertAfter('#question');
        $(document.createElement('form')).addClass('form').attr({method:'post', action:'mail.php', id: 'form'}).html('Please fill out the form').appendTo('#frame');
        $("<input type='text' name='yourname' id='yourname' placeholder='Your name' />").appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='text' name='municipality' id='municipality' placeholder='Your municipality' />").appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='text' name='email' id='email' placeholder='Your e-mail' />").appendTo('.form');
        $(document.createElement('header')).addClass('formheader').text('Give your municipality a point!').appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='radio' name='points' id='points1' title='1' value='1' />").appendTo(".form");
        $("<label for='points1' />").text('1').appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='radio' name='points' id='points2' title='2' value='2' />").appendTo('.form');
        $("<label for='points2' />").text('2').appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='radio' name='points' id='points3' title='3' value='3' />").appendTo('.form');
        $("<label for='points3' />").text('3').appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='radio' name='points' id='points4' title='4' value='4' />").appendTo('.form');
        $("<label for='points4' />").text('4').appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='radio' name='points' id='points5' title='5' value='5' />").appendTo('.form');
        $("<label for='points5' />").text('5').appendTo('.form');
        $(document.createElement('textarea')).addClass('mail_text').attr('id', 'text_mail').text('Please send us your story!').appendTo('.form');
        $("<input type='submit' id='sendForm' class='sendForm' name='sendForm' value='Press to send!'/>").appendTo('.form');
      }

    function sendForm() {
$('#form').submit(function(event){
    $('#sendForm').attr('value','Your answer was sent!');

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#sendForm').attr('value','Sending...');
    }, 2000);

    var stuff = $('#form').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mail.php', 
        data: stuff,
        dataType: "json"
    });

    //Prevents form submission
    return false;        
});
}
          function init() {
             //add title
             if (typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string") {
                 $(document.createElement('h1')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
             } else {
                 $(document.createElement('h1')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
             }

             //add pager and questions
             if (typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array") {
                 //add pager
                 $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id', 'pager').text('Q 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
                 //add first question
                 $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');
                 //add image if present
                 if (quiz[0].hasOwnProperty('image') && quiz[0]['image'] != "") {
                     $(document.createElement('img')).addClass('question-image').attr('id', 'question-image').attr('src', quiz[0]['image']).attr('alt', htmlEncode(quiz[0]['question'])).appendTo('#frame');
                 }
                 $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id', 'explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

                 //questions holder
                 $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame');

                 //add choices
                 addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);

                 //add submit button
                 $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('Nästa fråga').css({
                     'font-weight': 700,
                     'color': '#222',
                     'padding': '30px 0',
                  }).appendTo('#frame');


               $("#submitbutton").hide();
                 setupButtons();
             }
         }

         init();
     }); 

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id = "frame" role = "content"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

mail.php

```
<?php parse_str($_POST['stuff']);  mail("test@mymail.org", "Title", "$yourname, $email, $points, $text_mail");  ?>
```

Comment: Did you put your PHP in the backend, didn't you? I mean, Javascript runs on the client (browser's user) but PHP runs on a server with a PHP interpreter, the code you're showing us seems to put your PHP code below JS code, but I supose you have put your PHP code inside a file named *mail.php* in the same folder than your HTML file on the server... If so, where's the problem? You're just telling us that *you're having problems incorporating this in your script*, which problems?

Comment: *facepalm* of course i did! what is required in the php-document? and i can put everything above <?php> in the backend right?

Comment: In the php script you should only have this: ```<?php
parse_str($_POST['stuff']);

mail("aa@ss.com", "Title", "$yourname, $email, $points, $mail_text");

?>``` (actually you don't even need the close tag *?>*). And yes, you can put everything above <?php in the backend, but in this case, your script only gets some data from POST parameter and sends and email, I don't see why you would put anything above <?php tag. Maybe below to tell the user the mail is sent? (you should check the return value of *mail()*, and you could tell the user if the mail can be accepted for delivery)

Comment: cheers! but still can't get it to work, would appreciate it if you could have a look at my update if it helps.

Comment: just add ```print_r($_POST)``` at the begining of the mail.php and you'll see that there is no key in the ```$_POST``` named *stuff*. *Stuff* is your js variable, but the ```$_POST``` array is populated with the *name* attributes of the form, so you can skip the ```parse_str``` and get the email with ```$_POST['email']```. Oh, and your AJAX call doesn't need to be *json* type, your *mail.php* script is not returning any json data :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selectors seem to be mis-matched.

You are looking for .sendForm class on the submit handler, but your form attribute is ID'ed as #sendForm with a class of .submitForm

then you do it again, your form is CLASSED as .form from the addClass() method on create, but then you are trying to send #form Id's data, which doesn't exist.

```
$(document.createElement('form')).addClass('form')
```

vs

```
 stuff = $('#form').serialize();
```

It exaplins why nothing happes, as you aren't linking the elements to what you expect to have come in.

Comment: original post updated with changes but still doesn't work. been trying a couple of things and think this was some left over dirt. please see original post.

Comment: Refreshed, still same problem.

var stuff = $('#form').serialize(); is still looking for <form id="form"> but you have created dom element <form class="form"> which is why you get no data.

Comment: code right now: $(document.createElement('form')).addClass('form').attr({method:'post', action:'mail.php', id: 'form'}).html('Please fill out the form').appendTo('#frame'); also changed name of id of submit from submitForm to sendForm

Comment: Still same problem.  You need to change  var stuff = $('#form').serialize();  to var stuff = $('.form').serialize();

Comment: even though I added ID #form to the form? i tried changing stuff to target .form but still nothing happens.

Comment: Missed that attr() bit, sorry.  Yes, so those selectors should match now.  You should also note that using ids/classes of the element name is considered a bad practice.  You name things what they are, not what element they represent.   

 if you alert(stuff), do you see the data?   If so, try echo'ing out parse_str($_POST['stuff']); on the php end to make sure it makes it to the back end.    You are also missing a name attribute on the textarea.  That may or may not be an issue.